# What is Objective-C Posing and limitations of posing

Tags: objective-c

- Objective-C permits a class to wholly replace another class within a program.
- The replacing class is said to "pose as" the target class.
- Totally i was confused because of some ones says objective c posing deprecated

Comment: Yes it is deprecated